# What type is passing into function

Tags: c#

I have simple application which have one abstract class `BaseType`, and two derived classes `FirstDerived : BaseType` and `SecondDerived : BaseType`. In derived class i call function  `base.MakeChange(Item.ID);` to change value of instance of embedded property `Item`. It does not change. As i was explained because `base.MakeChange(Item.ID);` change not instance of `FirstDerived` , in function it creates another instance. But i thought that function `MakeChange` should get reference on `Item` because it's reference type. It seems that `MakeChange` get type value. Why? Where i am wrong?

```
namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Data d = new Data();
        Console.WriteLine(((FirstDerived)d.Items[0]).Item.ID);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
}

public abstract class BaseType
{
    public void MakeChange(string id)
    {
        id = "5";
    }
}

public class FirstDerived : BaseType
{
    public FirstDerived()
    {
        Item = new Item();
        Item.ID = "4";
        base.MakeChange(Item.ID);
    }
    public Item Item { get; set; }
}

public class SecondDerived : BaseType
{

    public SecondDerived()
    {
        Item = new Item();
        base.MakeChange(Item.ID);
    }
    public Item Item { get; set; }
}
public class Data
{
    public ObservableCollection <BaseType> Items { get; set; }

    public Data()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<BaseType>();
        Items.Add(new FirstDerived());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html might be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are resetting the value of the local scoped `id` inside the method, not the property passed in to the method.

If you want to do that, you have to make `id` pass-by-reference or just return the new value:

```
public string MakeChange(string id)
{
    return "5";
}

public void MakeChangeAsRef(ref string id)
{
    id = "5";
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
Item.ID = this.MakeChange(Item.ID);
```

Or as `ref`:

```
string id = Item.ID;
this.MakeChangeAsRef(ref id);
Item.ID = id;
```

Another option would be to pass in the `Item`.

(Don't call `base.` since it might break overriding that method one day. `this` will do the same job for now)

Comment: It should not work. A property, indexer or dynamic member access may not be passed as an out or ref parameter.

Comment: If I am not wrong string has reference type, why it's need to force it with ref?

Comment: You are resetting the reference of the local scoped `id`. It change `id` to become other than the referenced `item.ID`.

Answer (score 1):

1. public void MakeChange( Item item)
   Take Item Parameter As Object
2. base.MakeChange(Item);

In Your FirstDerived And SecondDerived